# Program suddenly has a spike in cpu usage and looks like it is paused

Tags: c, arrays, cpu-usage

I have added 2 functions:

```
int aiCheckScore(char arr[7][7], int inp, int height, Player player)

int aiFindMostRelevant(char arr[7][7], Player player)
```

The first makes a score for a given position in a 2D array. The score is equal to how many of the same kind elements we would have in a row (vertically, horizontally or diagonally and it keeps the best one of those 3) if we added one in this position (excluding the one we add just now)

The second function checks 7 positions at a time and finds the one with the best score and returns that. I tried to add a little randomness and make it so that if 2 positions have the same score the program would choose the last one 30% of the time (so that it wouldn't always take the first one).

Without the bit where I add the randomness the code runs just fine. As soon as I add it the program halts right after it calls for the 12th time the first function. Furthermore, the CPU usage from the program suddenly spikes and remains at 50% from below 5% it was before.

I have modified the code which creates the randomness a couple of times but nothing seems to change. I can't even comprehend why it would cause such an issue.

My 2 functions are:

```
int aiCheckScore(char arr[7][7], int inp, int height, Player player) {

    int i, j;
    int score[4] = { 0 };

    //check horizontal score
    for (i = inp - 1; i >= 0; i--) {        //everything left
        if (arr[height][i] != player.symb)
            break;

        ++score[0];
    }
    for (i = inp + 1; i <= 6; i) {          //everything right
        if (arr[height][i] != player.symb)
            break;

        ++score[0];
    }

    //check vertical score (we only have to check down)
    for (i = height + 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (arr[i][inp] != player.symb)
            break;

        ++score[1];
    }

    //check diagonal (which starts left and above and goes down and right)
    j = height - 1;
    for (i = inp - 1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--) {  //above and left        
        if (arr[j][i] != player.symb)
            break;

        ++score[2];
        --j;
    }
    j = height + 1;
    for (i = inp + 1; i <= 6 && j <= 6; i++) {  //down and right
        if (arr[j][i] != player.symb)
            break;

        ++score[2];
        ++j;
    }

    //check diagonal (which starts left and down and goes up and right)
    j = height + 1;
    for (i = inp - 1; i >= 0 && j <= 6; i--) {  //down and left     
        if (arr[j][i] != player.symb)
            break;

        ++score[3];
        ++j;
    }
    j = height - 1;
    for (i = inp + 1; i <= 6 && j >= 0; i++) {  //up and right
        if (arr[j][i] != player.symb)
            break;

        ++score[3];
        --j;
    }
    int bestscore = score[0];
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (score[i] > bestscore)
            bestscore = score[i];
    }
    printf("%d", bestscore);
    return bestscore;
}


int aiFindMostRelevant(char arr[7][7], Player player) {

    int i, height;

    int score[7] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        height = findHeight(arr, i);

        if (height == -1) {//skip the columns that are full
            score[i] = -100;                            //and give them a very bad score
        }
        else {
            score[i] = aiCheckScore(arr, i, height, player);
        }       
    }

    int bestscore = score[0];
    int bestposition = 0;
    int num;

    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {  
        num = (int)rand() % 10;

        if (score[i] == bestscore) {    //if 2 positions have the same score 

            if (num >= 7) {                 //there is a 30% chance the ai will take the new one to add some variety
                bestposition = i;
            }
        }

        if (score[i] > bestscore) { //always take the position with the best score
            bestscore = score[i];
            bestposition = i;
        }
    }

    return bestposition;
}
```

Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated and any suggestions to generally improve my code are welcome

Comment: Causes to these kind of issues can often be found with a debugger. I recommend using some time to learn the basic use of debugger. It will save a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is no increment in one of the loops.
Change:

`for (i = inp + 1; i <= 6; i)` to `for (i = inp + 1; i <= 6; ++i)`

and see if it helps.